# How to write SQL to return count of occurrences of join data?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

I have a table of houses and a join table of windows. So a house can have 0 or more windows, up to no limit (this is a contrived example, but it models what I'm working on).

I want to be able to write an SQL query that returns the counts of houses that have 0 windows, the counts that have 1 window, the counts that have 2 windows, etc.

I.e.:

```
# Windows | # Houses
--------------------
0         | 27
1         | 18
2         | 45
3         | 7
etc.
```

The tables are super simple.  Window has a "house_id" foreign key which references the House table's ID field.

I know this should be easy but for the life of me I can't figure it out?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Which DBMS are  you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: MySQL, although this should be standard enough that any SQL compliant DB should work I'd think

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to get desired output:

```
SELECT cnt AS `# Windows`, COUNT(*) AS `# Houses`
FROM (
SELECT house_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Window
GROUP BY house_id ) t
GROUP BY cnt
```

This is standard SQL, so it should work in most RDMBSs.

If you want `# Windows` field to contain all possible numbers, starting from 0 up to the maximum number of windows, then you have to create a tally table and `LEFT JOIN` with a derived table generated from the query above.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/874e2/2)

Comment: Giorgos, thanks for such a great answer! Only problem is that it doesn't show 0  I.e. houses that have no join records on the windows table.  Is there an easy way to add that in without doing a tally table?

Comment: BTW, thank you for introducing me to sqlfiddle! I've used jsfiddle before but had no idea there was one for SQL. Nice!

Comment: @DanSharp Is there a maximum number of windows a house can have?

Comment: Nope.  I suppose I could query to find the max then use that as a fixed max, but in general, there are no limits to how many join records for a given house

Comment: @DanSharp If you want to output a row for every 'gap' in your results, then I'm afraid you have to use a tally table. Have a look [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator) of how to build and use such a table in MySQL. In SQL Server you could use a recursive CTE instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add the "GROUP BY" clause.
Check this question [out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460225/sql-query-involving-group-by-and-joins)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `having` clause:

```
select count(*) 
from(select house from TableName
     group by house
     having count(*) = 1) t
```

Replace `1` with any number in which you are intrested.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT NUM_WINDOWS AS "# Windows", COUNT(*) AS "# Houses"
  FROM (SELECT HOUSE_ID, COUNT(*) AS NUM_WINDOWS
          FROM WINDOW
          GROUP BY HOUSE_ID)
  GROUP BY NUM_WINDOWS
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Bob, Thanks so much! However, this doesn't include houses with 0 windows, which I need. Is there a way to incorporate that?

Answer (score 0):

Well based on what you are saying this should do it:

The subquery gets a list of Houses and how many windows on each. The next counts the other way, houses with how many windows.

```
Select Window_ct, COUNT(house_id) House_Ct
From (select h.House_id, COUNT(w.Windows_Id) Window_Ct
        from Houses h
            inner join Windowz w
            On H.House_id = W.House.id
        Group by h.House_id) t
Group by Window_Ct
Order by 2
```