# How to combine 2 queries?

Tags: sql

I am Having trouble combining these 2 queries, My question here is how am I suppose to join these 2 queries? Do I use a Join? I want to combine these 2 queries because of certain requirements that I am working on. My use-case here is for showing if there are dates in the sdrp15 return table. Regarding my tables the only thing that links up these 2 queries are the state_code column and phase, these 2 columns are the only columns that show up in all my tables.

Query 1

```
 select a.phase,a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name AS CHG,
    case when a.submission_received_dt is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as Changes
    from pcspro.sdrp15_return a,
    pcspro.sdrp15_states_ready b 
    where a.phase = b.phase and a.st_code = b.state;
```

Result 1:

```
PHASE  STATE    CHG
```

---

```
   A   01 - AL   Y        
   A   11 - DC   Y     
   A   16 - ID   Y
```

Query 2

```
    select count(cou_code) as changes, state_code 
    from sdrp15_submission_log sl
    where  state_code in (select distinct state_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                          where  state_code = sl.state_code
                          and    cou_code  != 'All')
    and   qa_date  is null
    and   phase = 'A'                    
    group by state_code;
```

Results 2:

```
  CHANGES   STATE_CODE   

  -------- ------- 
       29   01          
       2    11        
       2    16
```

and What I want to do is combining them and my expected results should be:

```
  PHASE  STATE   CHG   CHANGES

 ------ ------- ------ --------
    A   01 - AL   Y       29 
    A   11 - DC   Y       02
    A   16 - ID   Y       02
    A   08 - HA   Y       NULL
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? What is your use-case? Can you write about your tables a bit?

Comment: Show us sample result for query 1 and sample result for query 2, and show us the combined result you want in that case!

Comment: Excellent. And the combined result looks like?

Comment: Your second query gets you one result row per state_code. But only for certain state_codes. Your first query gets you all state_codes present in the two tables used therein. This leads to questions: What to do if a state_code is present in thew first result set, but not in the second? And vice versa? And can there be more than one result row for a sinlge state_code in the first query?

Comment: Where does the last result line in your example come from? I see it neither in the first result set nor in the second.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460225/sql-query-involving-group-by-and-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd need more info. However, maybe the following will work for you (I haven't tested it!):

```
SELECT
    a.phase AS PHASE,
    a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name AS [STATE],
    CASE WHEN a.submission_received_dt IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS CHG,
    x.changes AS CHANGES
FROM pcspro.sdrp15_return a
INNER JOIN pcspro.sdrp15_states_ready b
    ON a.phase = b.phase AND a.st_code = b.state
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(cou_code) AS changes,
        state_code 
    FROM sdrp15_submission_log sl
    WHERE state_code IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT state_code
        FROM sdrp15_submission_log
        WHERE state_code = sl.state_code AND cou_code  != 'All')
      AND qa_date IS NULL AND phase = 'A'                    
    GROUP BY state_code; 
) x ON x.state_code = a.st_code
```

Edit according to the comment:

```
SELECT
    a.phase AS PHASE,
    a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name AS [STATE],
    CASE WHEN a.submission_received_dt IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS CHG,
    x.changes AS CHANGES_qa_date_null,
    y.changes AS CHANGES_qa_date_not_null
FROM pcspro.sdrp15_return a
INNER JOIN pcspro.sdrp15_states_ready b
    ON a.phase = b.phase AND a.st_code = b.state
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(cou_code) AS changes,
        state_code 
    FROM sdrp15_submission_log sl
    WHERE state_code IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT state_code
        FROM sdrp15_submission_log
        WHERE state_code = sl.state_code AND cou_code  != 'All')
      AND qa_date IS NULL AND phase = 'A'                    
    GROUP BY state_code; 
) x ON x.state_code = a.st_code
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(cou_code) AS changes,
        state_code 
    FROM sdrp15_submission_log sl
    WHERE state_code IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT state_code
        FROM sdrp15_submission_log
        WHERE state_code = sl.state_code AND cou_code  != 'All')
      AND qa_date IS NOT NULL AND phase = 'A'                    
    GROUP BY state_code; 
) y ON y.state_code = a.st_code
```

Comment: @e.go. one question,lets say we had a 3rd query that is just like the 2ndquery ( with the table sdrp15) instead of qa_date is null it would be not null. Can I add to the query above another join?